# error when get value of function

Tags: sql-server

i have this function

```
create function getmobnum(@input bigint)
RETURNS bigint
as
 begin
  declare @output varchar(10)='';
  declare @i int = 1;

while @i <= (len(@input)) begin
    declare @unicode varchar(1) = substring(cast(@input as varchar(10)), @i, 1);
    if @i>3 and @i<9 
    begin
       set @output=@output+'*';end
    else
       begin
       set @output=@output+@unicode;end
       set @i=@i+1;
end

return @output
end;
```

i call function here

```
declare @premob varchar(10)='';
set @premob= dbo.getmobnum(@premo);
```

but this error Occur

Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You function states that it will be returning a bigint, but @output which is returned is a varchar.

Change the function to also return a varchar.

### [SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/eb5e5/1)